# rpy2 installation error on Windows 8 (Anaconda)

Tags: python, rpy2, anaconda

I have the latest Anaconda Python distribution installed on Windows 8 and I am attempting to install the rpy2 package. I initially ran into several issues that I was able to circumvent but I'm now stuck on one particular error that I'm pasting below.

The command

```
pip install rpy2
```

exits with the following error message:

```
In file included from .\rpy\rinterface\_rinterface.c:58:0:

.\rpy\rinterface\_rinterface.h:8:15: fatal error: R.h: No such file or
directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Any suggestions? The path to R.h is included on my environment.

Comment: Try http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dr. Gohlke's binary is probably the easiest solution. But you need to change the `Python` installation path in your registry for this method to work. The relevant key is in **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath**. Change it so that the anaconda `Python` is the default `python` installation. You can always change it back if you want.

Comment: Well, this actually worked! I still can't seem to figure out what was causing the error earlier, but I guess that's besides the point now. Thanks :)

Comment: It is also way hard to install `rpy2` on a `win` machine. That's why we all appreciate Dr. Gohlke's binaries. :)

Comment: The default value is `Python 2.7`, should I change it to the absolute value of anaconda python?

Comment: Hi @CTZhu I am stuck with a simular error on Linux    `./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:86:31: fatal error:     readline/readline.h: No such file or directory
   
   compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`  Any suggestions?